# Incremental backup - How are changes identified

Tags: storage, backup-strategies

Have gone through several links, and though it explains what is incremental backup how are the difference since the last backup identified? is it by size of the files or the data... can anyone explain...else guide me to a reference for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the following information on the reference specified. Hope it helps out sm1.

```
The client considers a file changed if any of the following attributes changed since the last backup:
File size
Date or time of last modification
Extended Attributes
Access Control List

If only the following items change, they are updated without causing the entire file to be backed up to the server:

File owner
File permissions
Last access time
Inode
Group ID
```

Reference : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tsminfo/v6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itsm.client.doc%2Fc_bac_fullpart.html